# How do I create a System.IO.Stream from blob:https://localhost:5001/2b28e86c-fef1-482e-ae16-12466e6f729f

Tags: c#

I'm submitting a trusted url path to my webapi and then trying to upload the image to azure-storage. The uri I have to upload includes blob:https://localhost/...  Which points to a image stored locally. I need to read this stream however I'm receiving an exception on first line of code:

> "The URI prefix is not recognized."

```
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("blob:https://localhost:5001/2b28e86c-fef1-482e-ae16-12466e6f729f");
using (var stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
{

    containerClient.UploadBlob(image.guid.ToString(), stream);
}
```

Comment: did you try without blob: ?

Comment: Try removing `blob:` from the download URL of the image.

Comment: Blob URLs are created by client-side javascript. They only exist and work within the browser they were created in, the server doesn't know anything about them and won't be able to answer requests for them.

Answer (score 0):

I did a bunch more searching and discovered that only the browser can access blob: files. Ended up switching back to FormData.